# Why the function works locally but doesn't work from Dataflow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to post a request to Google Analytics with Data-flow. First step is to read appropriate parameters from Big-query - it works fine. Next is to use them in HTTP post request. Locally with providing explicit parameters it works but in Data-flow it does nothing on this step.

Here is my code (SendRequests class), where el - each data row in BQ.

```
class SendRequests(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SendRequests, self).__init__()
    def process(self, el):
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google-analytics.com")
        params = urllib.urlencode(el)
        conn.request("POST", "/collect", params)
        yield 1

locally:
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.google-analytics.com")
conn.request("POST", "/collect", params)
```

Comment: Try creating the conn in `start_bundle()` or preferably in `setup()` function (you have to override them), to avoid creating tons of connections. 
Ref: https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.22.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not "doing nothing"... check the log files.

Also, it maybe that the Dataflow jobs are running with private IP addresses only.  If that't he case, the function would not be accessible unless the Dataflow job AND the Function are in the same VPC.

I don't think you'll have to enable Google Private Access, but read this and see if it helps...  https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options

Gareth

Comment: the request status in logs is OK (200). but there is no new data in GA. I have enabled Google Private Access but it's still the same situation:/